# JAVA - Read the attributes of an XML node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, document

I am trying to read the lines of an XML file using the XPath library. So far I have been able to read each of the nodes of the document that I am processing but I don't know how to access a specific attribute of the node.

For a better understanding, I will give an example along with the code I have developed so far:

```
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
```

What I want to do is get the value of the value attribute that in the example all nodes contain the text "Spanish".

With the following code I read each of the lines but I don't know how to access the value of the attributes with the Java XPath library:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        String xPathExpression = "//string";

        Document documento = null;
        NodeList nodos = null;

        try {
            // Carga del documento xml
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            documento = builder.parse(new File("./src/TestResults/xmlFile.lang"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // Preparación de xpath
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            // Consultas
            nodos = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xPathExpression, documento, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        for (int i=0;i<nodos.getLength();i++){
            System.out.println("********* ITER " + i + " *********");
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getNodeName());
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getNodeValue());
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getAttributes());
            System.out.println("**************************");
        }

}
```

Comment: Try `nodos.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();`

Comment: Thanks @Smile .. that works exactly like I want !

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```java
nodos.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve, but if you want the value of the 'value' attribute, the XPath expression could be:

```
//string/@value
```

where '@' is shorthand for the `attribute`axis`. Could also be written as

```
//string/attribute::value
```